# IList<T> implementation

Tags: c#, performance, linked-list, collections

I was wondering about the possibility to create an implementation of `IList<T>` that is faster than `List<T>` using C#, or at least faster at adding elements.
I thought to try to write out one using a technique similar to the binary tree that just came up to my mind. Basically, each item is a pointer to a block of memory (let me call it *entry*) containing three more pointers:

1. A pointer to the item
2. A pointer to the previous entry
3. A pointer to the next entry

Here's my implementation, which is not complete yet, though:

```
public class FastList<T> : IList<T>
{

    private static readonly int sPtrSize = IntPtr.Size;
    private static readonly int sItemSize = sPtrSize * 3;
    private static readonly int sItemOffset = 0;
    private static readonly int sPreviousOffset = sItemSize - (sPtrSize << 1);
    private static readonly int sNextOffset = sItemSize - sPtrSize;

    private static IntPtr CreateItem() => Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sItemSize);

    private static GCHandle GetItemHandle(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        IntPtr itemPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, sItemOffset);
        return GCHandle.FromIntPtr(itemPtr);
    }

    private static void DeleteItem(IntPtr item)
    {
        GetItemHandle(item).Free();
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(item);
    }

    private static T GetItem(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GetItemHandle(ptr);
        return (T)handle.Target;
    }

    private static void SetItem(IntPtr ptr, T item)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(item, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr itemPtr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, sItemOffset, itemPtr);
    }

    private static IntPtr GetPrevious(IntPtr ptr) => Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, sPreviousOffset);

    private static void SetPrevious(IntPtr ptr, IntPtr previous) => Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, sPreviousOffset, previous);

    private static IntPtr GetNext(IntPtr ptr) => Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, sNextOffset);

    private static void SetNext(IntPtr ptr, IntPtr next) => Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, sNextOffset, next);

    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {

        private readonly FastList<T> mList;

        private int mPosition = -1;

        private IntPtr mCurrent = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Enumerator(FastList<T> list) => mList = list;

        public T Current => GetItem(mCurrent);

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (++mPosition >= mList.Count)
                return false;
            if (mCurrent == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                mCurrent = mList.mStart;
                return mList.Count != 0;
            }
            mCurrent = GetNext(mCurrent);
            return mCurrent != IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public void Reset() => mCurrent = mList.mStart;

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    private readonly IntPtr mStart = CreateItem();

    private IntPtr mEnd;

    public FastList()
    {
        SetNext(mStart, IntPtr.Zero);
        mEnd = mStart;
    }

    ~FastList() => DeleteItem(mStart);

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => GetItem(FindItem(index));
        set => SetItem(FindItem(index), value);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get;
    } = false;

    private IntPtr FindItem(int index)
    {
        int count = Count;
        IntPtr item;
        if (index < count >> 1)
        {
            item = mStart;
            for (; index != -1 && (item = GetNext(item)) != IntPtr.Zero; index--) ;
        }
        else
        {
            item = mEnd;
            index = count - index;
            for (; index != -1 && (item = GetPrevious(item)) != IntPtr.Zero; index--) ;
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        SetItem(mEnd, item);
        IntPtr previous = mEnd;
        mEnd = CreateItem();
        SetPrevious(mEnd, previous);
        SetNext(mEnd, IntPtr.Zero);
        SetNext(previous, mEnd);
        Count++;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        SetNext(mStart, IntPtr.Zero);
        for (IntPtr item = mStart; (item = GetNext(item)) != IntPtr.Zero;)
            DeleteItem(item);
        Count = 0;
    }

    private void RemoveItem(IntPtr item)
    {
        IntPtr previous = GetPrevious(item);
        IntPtr next = GetNext(item);
        SetNext(previous, next);
        SetPrevious(next, previous);
        DeleteItem(item);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) => IndexOf(item) != -1;

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public int IndexOf(T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        IntPtr next = FindItem(index);
        IntPtr previous = GetPrevious(next);
        IntPtr itemPtr = CreateItem();
        SetItem(itemPtr, item);
        SetPrevious(itemPtr, previous);
        SetNext(itemPtr, next);
        SetPrevious(next, itemPtr);
        SetNext(previous, itemPtr);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void RemoveAt(int index) => RemoveItem(FindItem(index));

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(this);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Unfortunately, however, it turns out that it is roughly 10 times slower than `List<T>`. I couldn't still understand why.
Could someone, please, tell me why it results so slow and suggest me how can I speed this up?

Comment: Can you be more specific about where (what operations) it is slower with?

Comment: _create an implementation of IList<T> that is faster than List<T>_ faster for lookup or manipulation of items?

Comment: This is ironic, `FastList` is slower than `List` :-) How did you measure and compare them?

Comment: SortedList is a built in list using a red black tree under the hood, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Sorry, my above comment should be SortedSet not SortedList

Comment: @t3chb0t, of course, FastList<T> is named after my purpose, even if I couldn't fulfill it yet. Regarding measurements, I used the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to perform measurements with different count of items to add to both FastList<T> and List<T> and I've taken the average of those measurements for either my list and the standard one.

Comment: On a more fundamental level, before you attempt to create "something like X, but faster", you should make sure you can answer these questions: 1) How does X work? 2) What does my thing do differently? 3) Why is that a faster way? Implicit in these questions is that you have some knowledge of what kind of code is fast in a modern computer.

Comment: Indeed, @Sebastian Redl, I'm aware how List<T> works in every detail, and I opted to use unmanaged memory instead of arrays, so I don't have to resize them (it would be slow as it is impossible to resize arrays, and so you'll end up allocating a brand new array and copy the data from the previous one to the latter). Rather, I have just to allocate more memory and update the next pointer of the previous entry to one that points out to this one.

Comment: Also, @Sebastian Redl, my method IS faster, the problem is, how it is to be implemented in C#, being it an interpreted language whose memory is fully managed by CLR, so that every attempt to work at a lower level would inevitably slow down the memory access. Talk to inexpert people, not those ones who know almost everything about CLR and how .NET languages work.

Comment: "my method IS faster" - For what? Appends? Inserts in the middle? Access? Iteration? The answer is actually *none of them*, unless your lists are quite large. Random pointer chasing is just that slow compared to simple sequential memory like `List` uses.

Comment: This time you're right, @Sebastian Redl. I should have specified. My method is faster at adding elements. Operations that have to do with indexes will result way slower. But at adding elements it is faster for sure!

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, it is slower both at adding elements and iterating through them. Not sure about everything else, as I just tested those two operations.

Comment: `List<T>.Add` is already as fast as it can possibly be, as it's basically just doing `_array[_count] = item; _count++;`.

Comment: You're allocating memory in `Add` so it's no surprise it's slower than `List<T>.Add` which has no allocation.

Comment: @Flavien, you're absolutely wrong. The step you're pointing out to is not the whole thing. If the array is too small to get a new element added, then it will be created a new, larger array; then the whole previous array will be copied into the newer one, and finally the item will be added to the newer array, which will replace the older one. Also, it's not even so simple: the actual List<T> implementation does something more I can't actually recall that would be needed if all elements are too many to be stored in any array. It does alot of things, though. It's not nearly as simple as you state

Comment: *(1)* The reallocation of the array is rare as the array doubles in size every time, so if you add 1000 items to a list, there will only be 8 memory allocations - versus 1000 in your case. *(2)* It can be avoided (or mitigated) most of the time by setting the capacity to a sensible value at creation, especially in performance critical code. *(3)* The reallocation is a single allocation and block copy and will be only maginally slower than the allocation you do in your `Add` on *every single call*.

Comment: I know, @Flavien. But List<T> memory allocations also require the previous array to be copied into the newer one. So, if, as you said, you have a List<T> and you add 1000 items to that, there are 8 memory allocations and 8 times that the list if fully iterated and copied: 1) 4 items being copied; 2) 8 items being copied; 3) 16 items being copied; and so on. Finally, you'll have copied 1020 items, which is even more than the number of items itself!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98090/discussion-between-davide-cannizzo-and-flavien).

Comment: That's not how the copy is done. Iterating the list would be terribly slow and would cause allocations. It's done using a block copy which is a native operation and will copy the entire array in (more or less) one CPU operation. The size of the array being copied practically doesn't matter. It will be almost as fast copying 10,000 items as copying 10 items. And certainly many orders of magnitude faster than iterating the array.

Comment: Block copy has anyway its overhead. An efficient way (of course, mine isn't) that avoids copying arrays would be much faster!

Comment: I guess the biggest improvement is going to be in your iterations when using unsafe as you can eliminate bounds checking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called a doubly linked list. `List<T>` is basically a wrapper around an array. The only operations where you can hope to be faster are insertions and deletions from the middle of the list.

---

Using `Marshal` unless you absolutely have to is a bad idea, if not a plain crazy one. This code has memory leaks (how is that destructor meant to release all of the memory allocated for the list? See also the next subsection). And because you're fighting the GC and the JIT, you can't expect high performance.

---

> ```
>     public void Clear()
>     {
>         SetNext(mStart, IntPtr.Zero);
>         for (IntPtr item = mStart; (item = GetNext(item)) != IntPtr.Zero;)
>             DeleteItem(item);
>         Count = 0;
>     }
> ```

Expand that `for` as a `while` and see whether you can spot the problems:

```
    SetNext(mStart, IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr item = mStart;
    while ((item = GetNext(item)) != IntPtr.Zero)
        DeleteItem(item);
```

> 1. `SetNext(mStart, IntPtr.Zero)` guarantees that the loop body never executes.
>  2. `DeleteItem(item)` before `GetNext(item)` is a use-after-free bug.

---

I can't figure out whether `mStart` is a sentinel or an actual element of the list. It seems to do both in different places. Comments!

---

What happens if I modify the list while iterating through it with the enumerator? Is this desirable?

---

I can't think of any good reason to implement `IList<T>` and not also implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Answer (score 8):

You've essentially built a doubly-linked list that also performs its own memory management.

Regarding linked lists:

- This makes indexing is an \$O(n)\$ operation, compared to \$O(1)\$ for `List<T>`. Searching from the end for indexes beyond the center helps, but it does not fundamentally change this performance characteristic.
- Adding is an \$O(1)\$ operation, similar to `List<T>` (which is \$O(1)\$ on average).
- Inserting and removing-at can also be \$O(1)\$, but only if you provide the right API (for an example, see `LinkedList<T>`'s `AddAfter/Before/First/Last` methods). Your current implementation is \$O(n)\$, similar to `List<T>`.
- Like `List<T>`, iterating is \$O(n)\$, but having to follow a chain of pointers will make it slower than `List<T>`, which stores its items in a contiguous block of memory. Pointer-chasing is also less cache-friendly.

---

Regarding custom memory management, GCHandles allow you to access managed objects from unmanaged code, but you don't have any unmanaged code here. This only introduces problems:

- It limits your list to only types that do not contain reference fields (`Add` will throw an `ArgumentException` (Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.) for all but the most basic types).
- It involves extra allocations, which take additional time and memory.
- It introduces the risk of leaking memory/handles.
- Pinning objects can make the garbage collector less efficient - it'll hinder memory compaction.
- Unexpected program terminations.

Creating a small `LinkedListNode<T>` class instead would be a much better idea.

---

There are also other problems with your code:

- Indexing is broken: `list[0]` returns the second item, while the first item is located at `list[-1]`... and around the center, a higher index might actually give you an earlier item.
- There's no bounds-checking: `list[-2]` and `list[list.Count + 2]` result in an `AccessViolationException` (if you're lucky) rather than an `OutOfRangeException`.
- `RemoveAt` seems to be implemented, but it fails with an `InvalidOperationException` (if it doesn't cause the program to terminate instead).

Comment: Also a LinkedListNode can be pooled (externally offcourse, just like the built in LinkedList) and result in zero strain on the GC which is important in real time systems.